# Why isn't the list data being converted?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, soql, javascript, javascript-controller, helper

I have a method that gets a list of data from a database, transforms some fields and outputs them to a table.

**//helper**

```
getDataFromDB : function(component, helper){
        let action = component.get('c.getListContacts');
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
           let state = response.getState();
               if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                   let rows = response.getReturnValue();
                   for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                       let row = rows[i];
                       if (row.Account) {
                           row.AccountName = row.Account.Name;
                       };
                       if(row.Owner) {
                           row.OwnerName = row.Owner.Name;
                       };
                       if(row.CreatedBy) {
                           row.CreatedByName = row.CreatedBy.Name;
                       };
                    }
                    component.set("v.contacts", rows);
                    helper.calculateAmountPage(component);
                    helper.getDisplayDataPagination(component);
                }
        });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**//apxc**

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Contact> getListContacts(){
    List<Contact> listContacts = [SELECT  Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate  FROM  Contact];
    System.debug('Get list contact info: ' + listContacts);
    return listContacts;
}
```

I also have a method that saves a new record and updates the information in the table with the new item.

**//helper**

```
createContact : function(component, helper, newContact){
    let action = component.get("c.createContact");
    action.setParams({
        "newContact" : newContact
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let contacts = component.get("v.contacts");
                let rows = response.getReturnValue();
                   for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                       row = rows[i];
                       if (row.Account) {
                           row.AccountName = row.Account.Name;
                       };
                       if(row.Owner) {
                           row.OwnerName = row.Owner.Name;
                       };
                       if(row.CreatedBy) {
                           row.CreatedByName = row.CreatedBy.Name;
                       };
                    }
                contacts.push(rows);
                component.set("v.contacts", contacts);
                helper.calculateAmountPage(component);
                helper.getDisplayDataPagination(component);
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**//apxc**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Contact createContact(Contact newContact){
        upsert newContact;
        Contact contact = [SELECT  Name, Email, Contact_Level__c, Account.Name, Owner.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate
            FROM  Contact WHERE Id = :newContact.Id];
        System.debug('Create contact info: ' + contact);
        return contact;
    }
```

But the problem is that the fields that I convert after getting from the database in this case are no longer converted and their values ​​are empty in the table.
This is what I get in the list after the "getDataFromDB" method works:

```
    {"Name":"Jack Johns","Email":"test@email.com","Contact_Level__c":"Primary","AccountId":"sdfsd54654sdf899465d4f",
"OwnerId":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedById":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedDate":"2021-02-07T20:49:46.000Z",
"Id":"sdfsdseLKFekefffEJK","Account":{"Name":"Oil & Gas","Id":"eKJNKJenkjfnKJEF5e4fee"},
"Owner":{"Name":"Jack Smile","Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"},"CreatedBy":{"Name":"Jack Smile",
"Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"},"AccountName":"Oil & Gas","OwnerName":"Jack Smile",
"CreatedByName":"Jack Smile"}
```

and this is what I get in the list after the "createContact" method works:

```
{"Name":"name1 name2","Email":"name1@name2.com","Contact_Level__c":"Primary","AccountId":"sdfsd54654sdf899465d4f",
"OwnerId":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedById":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedDate":
"2021-03-14T13:34:14.000Z","Id":"0087dp00003gWkdAAE","Account":{"Name":"Oil & Gas","Id":"eKJNKJenkjfnKJEF5e4fee"},"Owner":{"Name":"Jack Smile","Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"},
"CreatedBy":{"Name":"Jack Smile", "Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"}}
```

For some reason, this part is missing:

```
"AccountName":"Oil & Gas","OwnerName":"Jack Smile", "CreatedByName":"Jack Smile"}
```

This is also my init method:

```
init : function (component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
       { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Contact Level', fieldName: 'Contact_Level__c', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Account', fieldName: 'AccountName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'OwnerName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Created By', fieldName: 'CreatedByName', type: 'text', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'date', sortable: true  },
       { label: 'Action', type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: { label: 'Del', name: "delete", variant: 'destructive', onclick: '{!c.deleteTableRows}' },
    },
       ]);
    helper.getDataFromDB(component, helper);
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createContact` returns a Contact, not an Array of Contact values. You don't need the for loop. You didn't get an error, because rows.length is undefined, and 0 > undefined, so the loop ends without a single execution.

Your code should look like:

```
let contact = response.getReturnValue();
contact = { ...contact, 
  AccountName: contact.Account && contact.Account.Name, 
  OwnerName: contact.Owner && contact.Owner.Name, 
  CreatedByName: contact.CreatedBy && contact.CreatedBy.Name 
};
contacts.push(contact);
```

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank. I can also change the return type of the createContact method to List (so that the conversion mechanism remains the same).